# Converting from PyQt4 signal to PyQt5 signal doesn't work

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, signals-slots, pyqt5

I am trying to convert a game from PyQt4 to PyQt5 and I am having some difficulty converting to the newer signal types. So I have gone back into the original and I am trying to convert the signal first using PyQt4. The commented line is the old (working) version, underneath it the new version. However the 'new' version is always passing the same value to the event handler: 0. I have tried many subtly different versions, nothing seems to work. Ideas?

```
    self.cellButtonNames = [self.ui.cell0Button,  self.ui.cell1Button,  self.ui.cell2Button,  self.ui.cell3Button,  self.ui.cell4Button,  self.ui.cell5Button,
                                        self.ui.cell6Button, self.ui.cell7Button,  self.ui.cell8Button,  self.ui.cell9Button,  self.ui.cell10Button,  self.ui.cell11Button, 
                                        self.ui.cell12Button,  self.ui.cell13Button,  self.ui.cell14Button,  self.ui.cell15Button,  self.ui.cell16Button,  self.ui.cell17Button, 
                                        ...,
                                        self.ui.cell126Button,  self.ui.cell127Button,  self.ui.cell128Button,  self.ui.cell129Button,  self.ui.cell130Button,  self.ui.cell131Button,
                                        self.ui.cell132Button,  self.ui.cell133Button,  self.ui.cell134Button,  self.ui.cell135Button,  self.ui.cell136Button,  self.ui.cell137Button,
                                        self.ui.cell138Button,  self.ui.cell139Button,  self.ui.cell140Button,  self.ui.cell141Button,  self.ui.cell142Button,  self.ui.cell143Button]

    # This will connect all of the ball buttons to one slot (Event Handler) and pass the cell number to that event handler when signalled.
    # This elimates the need for 144 event handling methods! :-)

    cellNumber = 0
    for buttonName in self.cellButtonNames:
        # self.connect(buttonName, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), lambda who=cellNumber: self.ballClicked(who))
        buttonName.clicked.connect(lambda who=cellNumber: self.ballClicked(who))
        cellNumber += 1

@QtCore.pyqtSignature("")                                                                           # otherefore only want ne signal for this autoconnect.
def ballClicked ( self, cellNumber):
    print("Ball %i clicked" % cellNumber)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a well-known "gotcha".

There are a few signals (like `clicked` and `triggered`) that have default parameter that always sends a value. For buttons and actions, this is a `bool` representing their current checked state (even though they may not have been set checkable).

To work around this, you can connect your signals like this:

```
    buttonName.clicked.connect(
        lambda checked, who=cellNumber: self.ballClicked(who))
```

However, in this particular case, you might also want to consider using a [QButtonGroup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html) instead. That would only require *one* signal connection, and, as a side-benefit, you'd also get a ready-made interface for managing the buttons.

Comment: First off... It works!!! Thanks  a lot! Second, I'm not sure I understand this completely. You are 'passing' a tuple to the lambda function? Then how come only one variable gets there? I like the idea of the QButtonGroup, but since this is for an intro class, they are building in Designer, and I don't see that one in designer... :-(

Comment: @Arana. It's not a tuple. There's two arguments: the first one accepts the value sent by the signal, and the second has your default value. The first argument just gets thrown away. You can create button groups in Qt Designer by selecting the buttons, and then picking "Assign to button group" in the right-click menu (at least two buttons must be selected).

Comment: Got it! !  (insert dope slap here!) Thanks, that's twice you've save my bacon! I guess I was overlooking the lambda function in between! I owe you a virtual beer! Have two on me! :-D